# Java. Checking the type of an Anonymous Implementation of an Interface

Tags: java, interface, implementation, anonymous

I'm working with wicket, building a set a decoupled components. While using the event driven mechanism to let components communicate, I'm keeping a Set in the class "GenericComponent".
The basic idea is to send an event, with a "Someevent.class" as payload that extends from IGenericEvent. Then in the onEvent method from the GenericComponent class, go through all the events added to the Set. If the class matches the payload, then the event should be executed.

Now some code:

GenericComponent

```
public class  GenericComponent<T> extends GenericPanel<T>
{
//...
    protected Set<IGenericEvent>eventSet = new HashSet<IGenericEvent>(); 
//...

    public void addEvent(final IGenericEvent event)
    {
        boolean result = eventSet.add(event);
        if (!result)
        {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Event already added ...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(final IEvent<?> event)
    {
        for (IGenericEvent e : eventSet)
        {

            if (e.getClass().equals(event.getPayload()))
            {

                e.action(this.getContainer());
            }

        }
        update();
    }

}
```

IGenericEvent

```
public interface  IGenericEvent
{

    public void action(final WebMarkupContainer container);

}
```

HideEvent

```
public class Hide implements IGenericEvent, Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void action(WebMarkupContainer container)
    {
        container.setVisible(false);

    }

}
```

The problem:

If I define the onAction Event implementing the IGenericEvent as described before, everything is ok.

The problem is when I do it in the page it self, as an Anonymous Implementation of the interface. Then, the class would be PageSomething$1,2,3.

```
errorMessage.add(new Hide()
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onAction(Component component)
    {
        System.out.println("here");
    }


});
```

I have already tried with isAsignableFrom and Class.isIntance, but it does indeed makes sense; the class of the anonymous implementation is PageSomething. So isAsignableFrom or isInstance wont apply.

I refuse to believe that I should use some Generics to get the actual Class/Interface being used. Something like

`AbstractEvent<Hide>.`

I hope you guys understand the problem.

Thanks in advance.